# Laptop sort of freezes during overnight playback using VLC

Tags: 14.04, mouse, vlc, freeze, tty

I'm not sure if this is a VLC or Ubuntu issue. 
I generally leave VLC playing overnight with a long playlist of files playing from my local NAS. More often than not, I'll wake up in the morning and the audio is still playing fine, but the screen has frozen. The video is still on the frame it was when the freeze took place and Ubuntu's time has frozen. The mouse pointer still moves around as usual, but I can't click on anything. Pressing keys has no effect, apart from Ctrl + Alt + an F number to get to my other ttys, but they just bring up a black screen and I can't login to a terminal. Does anyone have any advice on how I can figure out what is going wrong, or if anyone has experienced a similar problem and can give me a fix?

Apologies if I've left out any vital information, please just comment and I will update the question.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1.) If your PC is still playing from NAS, you should be able to log in using ssh (if server is installed). This way you can kill vlc.

2.) Add a cron job to kill vlc in the morning. This will also show you if the vlc is the reason for the freezing screen or if some thing else is going on.